# Removing extra spaces from a file

Tags: java

I'm trying this code, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've initialized the string already, but getting an error for not initializing it.

Instead of replaceAll(), any other efficient *method()* or code would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
class Rspace
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int arr[] = new int[3];
        if(arr.length<2)
            {
                System.out.print("Parameters are missing");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        if(arr.length>2)
            {
                System.out.print("No. of parameters are exceeded");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        File f = new File(args[0]);
        if(!f.exists())
            {
                System.out.print("File does not exists");
                System.exit(2);
            }
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
        int ch;
        String str;
        while((ch=fis.read())!=-1) //Reading character & returning ASCII value;shifting to next character
            {
                fos.write(ch);
                str.replaceAll("\\s",""); //Removes all WhiteSpaces
            }
            fis.close();
            fos.close();    
    }
}
```

Comment: What value do you think `str` has when you invoke `replaceAll` on it? Why do you think so?

Comment: that's not even the problem. ``str`` never gets assigned a value, it stays unitialized.

Comment: you're reading individual chars, then suddenly dealing with strings..

Comment: You could initialize `str` as an empty string to avoid the error: `String str = ""`.  But you really should review what you are trying to do since this would only apply `replaceAll` to an empty string.

Comment: Any suggestions then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of whitespaces then you could do it that way:

```
import java.io.*;

class Rspace {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int arr[] = new int[3];
        if (arr.length < 2) {
            System.out.print("Parameters are missing");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (arr.length > 2) {
            System.out.print("No. of parameters are exceeded");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        File f = new File(args[0]);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            System.out.print("File does not exists");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
        int ch;
        boolean lastSpace = false;
        while ((ch = fis.read()) != -1) // Reading character & returning ASCII
                                        // value;shifting to next character
        {
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
                fos.write(ch);
                lastSpace = false;

            } else if (!lastSpace) {
                fos.write(ch);
                lastSpace = true;
            }
        }
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

You don't need something with string. For spaces I have added a boolean variable to check if we had a space already.
I hope it helps.